# Transfer data using Bundles from Fragment to Fragment and read it from another Fragment using same key

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have 4 [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments) in my app.On `First` Fragment based on some conditions I am transferring data from Fragment `First` to `Third` or `Fourth`.I am passing the data, and reading the data using `Bundles` with same Key names all over Fragments.
But I am not able to receive data send from Fragments send by other screens.
This is code for condition and send data using `Bundle` from Fragment `First`

```
saveSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(feedbackAction.equals("rating_good")) {
                        bundle.putString("id", myId);
                        bundle.putString("No", no);
                        fdb.setArguments(bundle);
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,fdb);
                        tx.addToBackStack("TabInfo");
                        tx.commit();
                    } else if(feedbackAction.equals("rating_bad")) {
                         bundle.putString("id", myId);
                        bundle.putString("No", no);
                        fdb.setArguments(bundle);
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,bfd);
                        tx.addToBackStack("TabInfo");
                        tx.commit();
                    }

            }
        });
```

This is code for retrieving data from `Second` Fragment

```
id=getArguments().getString("id");
    my_no=getArguments().getString("No");
```

This is code to retrieve data from `Fourth` Fragment

```
id=getArguments().getString("id");
        my_no=getArguments().getString("No");
```

But  I am getting error as
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`
How to get retrieve this Bundle data in other Fragments with Same Key ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you can follow, use fragments for ui and handle fragment, activity changes in activity. What you can do is to create an interface and implement that interface in your activity that uses the fragment like this.

```
 public interface OnActionClickedListener {

        void onSessionClicked(String name);

    }
```

In your fragment, you need to initialize this listener.

```
OnActionClickedListener onActionClickedListener;

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onActionClickedListener = (MyFragment.OnActionClickedListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }

    }
```

Now in your onClickListener on fragment you can just call

```
onActionClickedlistener.onSessionClicked("string you want to enter");
```

And at last your activity should extend MyFragment.OnActionClickedListener and implement the method onSessionClicked where you will change the fragment displayed. You can easily reach the data hold in activity from fragment. This way if  another activity uses your fragment, that activity can also implement the onActionClickedListener according to it's needs.